# How to loop through an array of objects using *ngFor

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, frontend

I want to loop through an array of objects using *ngFor 
For more explanation see below  :

```
[
     {sn: 'N300W150726', merchantName: ' test''}
     {sn: 'N300W150726', merchantName: 'alex', }
     {sn: 'N300W150726', merchantName: 'alexa',}
]
```

Once I want to pass clicked data due the function I got an error
my function shown below

```
    <button nbButton (click)="getTpeByUser(item.sn)">
              {{ item.merchantName}}
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see totally nothing? Then check toggle variable. Is the list not showing? Then check the nameUsersByType Array. BTW: the array elements are not separated by commas. Is this true? Then look there for your answer

Comment: Suddenly it works fine :)